# How can I use ViewBag in the View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

how i can  display "Name - LastName" with ViewBag?

```
<h2> @{ViewBag.Name;} - @{ViewBag.LastName;} </h2>
```

I have error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know what you pass via the ViewBag, but do remove the brackets

```
<h2> @ViewBag.Name - @ViewBag.LastName </h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<h2> @ViewBag.Name - @ViewBag.LastName </h2>
```

you only need `@`.

I strongly suggest you to start using strongly typed views instead of using ViewBag. strongly typed views keeps your views  ( and code ) clean and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2> @ViewBag.Name - @ViewBag.LastName </h2>
```

avoid the extra { and you are good